# How to change runtime type in google colab when the change runtime type option does not show?

Tags: java, google-colaboratory

I would like to run java in colab.

I successfully installed ijava and reloaded the page, but the "change runtime type" option does not show.

In this case, how do I switch from Python to Java kernel? Is there a command line trick by which I could manage to do it?

This is my colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XyVBfMJ3m23IsDVjPER7G-UZ0vd4gT2c?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to change to `ijava` is to download the notebook. Open it with a text editor and edit it manually.

So normally, you would use a pre-edited notebook. At the start, it cannot find `ijava` so it will use python3. After you install `ijava`, and reload, it will then use `ijava`.

Here's a shortcut to a pre-edited ijava notebook

https://colab.to/java

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @korakot any idea why this technique is no longer working after reload? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74674688/ijava-notebook-stuck-at-connecting-after-installation-refresh

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer above, here is a more detailed step-by-step set of instructions for how to install and configure IJava along with some examples.

**Instructions for installing and configuring the Java kernel**

https://medium.com/@gmsharpe/jupyter-java-and-google-colab-7a2f7fb08808

**IJava**

https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava