# Google Colab notebook using IJava stuck at "Connecting" after installation + refresh

Tags: python, java, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

All of my notebooks stopped connecting, after the initial IJava installation and browser page refresh.

**What used to work**

1. Execute this first cell

```
!wget https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/releases/download/v1.3.0/ijava-1.3.0.zip 
!unzip ijava-1.3.0.zip 
!python install.py --sys-prefix
```

2. Wait for the `Installed java kernel` message
3. Refresh the browser page.
4. Execute any cell with Java code.

**Now what happens is**

I can execute the first cell and get the `Installed java kernel` message, seeing the notebook status as "Connected".

But after refreshing the page, the status of the notebook is stuck at "Connecting" forever,

and thus no cells can be executed.

--

I'm using Google Colab for free, but since the initial installation still works, and the notebook status is "Connected" before the page is refreshed, this should not be the problem.

Any idea what has been changed, and how I can get my Java notebooks to connect again?

--

**UPDATE 1**

After the page reloads, when I try to run a cell containing Java code, this is the error message I'm getting after a while:

```
await connected: disconnected
@https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/5f9fa09db4e185842380071022f6c9a6/external_polymer_binary_l10n__en_gb.js:6249:377
promiseReactionJob@[native code]
```

Also, the notebook settings are

Runtime type: `java`

Hardware accelerator: `None`

The cells contain really simple Java code, no external libraries, no CPU or GPU intensive stuff.

For debugging purposes I tried running other cells (like the one with the Java installation, or Python code) - but of course, they also do not execute without connection.

--

**UPDATE 2**

After installing IJava and before the page reload, I noticed that the path for the Java kernel is different than the path for the "preinstalled" ir and python3 kernels:

```
!jupyter kernelspec list

 Available kernels:
  ir         /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  java       /usr/share/jupyter/kernels/java
```

Could that be the problem?

(I have never checked this before, so I don't know whether the default-path has been changed recently.)

This is the metadata content of the ipynb file:

```
{
    "nbformat": 4,
    "nbformat_minor": 0,
    "metadata": {
        "colab": {
            "provenance": [{
                "file_id": "...",
                "timestamp": 1670411565504
            }, {
                "file_id": "...",
                "timestamp": 1670311531999
            }, {
                "file_id": "...",
                "timestamp": 1605675807586
            }],
            "authorship_tag": "..."
        },
        "kernelspec": {
            "name": "java",
            "display_name": "java"
        }
    },
    "cells": [{
       ...
    ]}
}
```

Comment: I tried to add "language_info" : { "name" : "java" } below "kernelspec" - still no luck.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue... I have written a ton of content using this IJava in Google Colab, so I hope we can resolve this... :)

Comment: Somebody from Google replied to the issue here https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3267 , assuming it had to do with their Python 3.8 upgrade... 

Spencer Park (IJava author) added some debug info, too. (But no fix yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point colab changed the default transport to `ipc` (from the default `tcp`) which is not supported by IJava.

> `/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip=... --transport=ipc --port=...`

The kernel starts but never properly connects and doesn't send the initial kernel info message that jupyter is waiting for.

When/if there comes a point where we can ask to start up with `tcp` transport instead, that will be preferable (see https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3267) but for the time being we can work around it.

The workaround is to stick a little local proxy in front of the java kernel that connects all the ipc channels and forwards them to another set of tcp channels that are connected to the java kernel.

The first cell is still the usual install/setup but also includes the install for the proxy as well:

```bash
%%sh
# Install java kernel
wget -q https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/releases/download/v1.3.0/ijava-1.3.0.zip 
unzip -q ijava-1.3.0.zip 
python install.py

# Install proxy for the java kernel
wget -qO- https://gist.github.com/SpencerPark/e2732061ad19c1afa4a33a58cb8f18a9/archive/b6cff2bf09b6832344e576ea1e4731f0fb3df10c.tar.gz | tar xvz --strip-components=1
python install_ipc_proxy_kernel.py --kernel=java --implementation=ipc_proxy_kernel.py
```

Run that cell. You may have `Unrecognized runtime "java"; defaulting to "python3"` which is ok. After the cell runs with output similar to:

```
Installed java kernel into "/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/java"
e2732061ad19c1afa4a33a58cb8f18a9-b6cff2bf09b6832344e576ea1e4731f0fb3df10c/install_ipc_proxy_kernel.py
e2732061ad19c1afa4a33a58cb8f18a9-b6cff2bf09b6832344e576ea1e4731f0fb3df10c/ipc_proxy_kernel.py
Moving java kernel from /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/java...
Wrote modified kernel.json for java_tcp in /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/java_tcp/kernel.json
Installing the proxy kernel in place of java in /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/java
Installed proxy kernelspec: {"argv": ["/usr/bin/python3", "/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/java/ipc_proxy_kernel.py", "{connection_file}", "--kernel=java_tcp"], "env": {}, "display_name": "Java", "language": "java", "interrupt_mode": "message", "metadata": {}}
Proxy kernel installed. Go to 'Runtime > Change runtime type' and select 'java'
install.py:164: DeprecationWarning: replace is ignored. Installing a kernelspec always replaces an existing installation
  install_dest = KernelSpecManager().install_kernel_spec(
```

follow the printed instruction: `Go to 'Runtime > Change runtime type' and select 'java'`. The runtime should now show "Connected to java..." and you should be able to write and execute java code.

Try https://colab.research.google.com/gist/SpencerPark/447de114fcd3e6a272dc140809462e30 for an example base notebook.

---

That setup cell should be everything you need to get running, but here is a bit of an explanation for what is in the proxy kernel. It is published as a gist (https://gist.github.com/SpencerPark/e2732061ad19c1afa4a33a58cb8f18a9). The general idea is:

1. rename the real kernel with the `_tcp` suffix (`java_tcp`) and install the proxy in it's place with the intended name (`java`).
2. start the proxy kernel and bind everything as if the proxy is a kernel itself.

   ```py
   shell_socket = create_and_bind_socket(shell_port, zmq.ROUTER)
   stdin_socket = create_and_bind_socket(stdin_port, zmq.ROUTER)
   control_socket = create_and_bind_socket(control_port, zmq.ROUTER)
   iopub_socket = create_and_bind_socket(iopub_port, zmq.PUB)
   hb_socket = create_and_bind_socket(hb_port, zmq.REP)
   ```
3. start the real kernel with supported params (transport `"tcp"`) and the same session information. This is important so we can forward messages directly to the real kernel without decoding them in between.

   ```py
   kernel_manager = KernelManager()
   kernel_manager.kernel_name = args.kernel
   kernel_manager.transport = "tcp"
   kernel_manager.client_factory = ProxyKernelClient
   kernel_manager.autorestart = False

   kernel_manager.session.signature_scheme = signature_scheme
   kernel_manager.session.key = key

   kernel_manager.start_kernel()
   ```
4. start a zmq proxy for each pair of channels (this all the `ProxyKernelClient` does).

   ```py
   Thread(target=zmq.proxy, args=(proxy_server_socket, self.kernel_client_socket)).start()
   ```
5. then we are done! Just wait for the managed kernel process to exit, and then exit ourselves as well.

   ```py
   exit_code = kernel_manager.kernel.wait()
   kernel_client.stop_channels()
   zmq_context.destroy(0)
   exit(exit_code)
   ```

Comment: You are my hero! I can confirm that this workaround works like a charm!